# Command.execute issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I will try to explain this the best I can, however, it is a little confusing. Here is my code for executing a slash command.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction, Servers, Tickets, client);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [errorEmbed], ephemeral: true });
    }
});
```

If I put `client` right before `Servers`, it allows me to use it in other commands, however, if I put it later such as after `Tickets`, it doesn't work. This also happens when I move `Tickets` or `Servers` to the end I can no longer use those in the commands. Any ideas on why this could be?

Comment: How do you call `execute` in your commands?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros    async execute(interaction, Tickets, Servers) {} would add client there if I wanted to use it, but even if I don't call client in my commands, Servers still won't work anymore since its inside the command.execute

Comment: But you already swapped `Tickets` and `Servers`. The order must be the same. If you pass `client` as the fourth argument, it will be the fourth one in every single command file.

Comment: Oh? What if I don't want to call all 4 in my command file? @ZsoltMeszaros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `command.execute(interaction, Servers, Tickets, client)`, the order of the arguments must be the same in every command file. Even if you don't need the variables `Servers` or `Tickets`, if you want to use the `client`, it's the fourth argument.

It would be better to pass a single object:

```js
command.execute({ client, interaction, Servers, Tickets })
```

And in your command files, destructure the object to pick the ones you need:

```js
async execute({ client, interaction }) {
  // ...
```

```js
async execute({ Servers }) {
  // ...
```

This way the order no longer matters, but you'll still need to update every command file with those curly brackets.

Comment: you're great thank you so much, I shoulda realized  this but late-night coding isn't fun :D